# Find where a value matches and concatentate into column vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have cells saved as `Data`, `Date`, `Lat`, `Lon`, and `uID`. There are 1210 cells and each cell has either 365 or 366 days. The 1210 cells are the total number of sites for 2008-2014 (so there are a lot of repeats - for a site that has data from 2008-2014, it would show up 7 times). The 365 or 366 rows in each of these cells are the data for one year for that location for the years.

How can I find the indexes where the the Date matches and concatenate all the `Data`, `uID`, `Lat`, and `Lon` into on column? Right now, Data{i} would have the data for one site for one year, but I want to combine the data, lat, and lon information for one day into separate `Data`, `Lat`, and `Lon` columns, then move on to the next cell, which would have that information for the next day. That way, I can eventually plot the data in one day by just running through the columns.

Sample of a few cells

`Data` Size 1x1210

`Data{366}(1:14)` Size 366x1

Small sample:

```
    '8'  
    '10.9'
    '9.7'
    '8.9'
    '10.2'
    '8.8'
    '13.5'
    '6.7'
    '10' 
    '15.8'
    '11.6'
    '12.9'
    '11.8'
    '10.2'
```

`Date{366}(1:14)` Same size as `Data`

```
'01-Jan-2011'
'02-Jan-2011'
'03-Jan-2011'
'04-Jan-2011'
'05-Jan-2011'
'06-Jan-2011'
'07-Jan-2011'
'08-Jan-2011'
'09-Jan-2011'
'10-Jan-2011'
'11-Jan-2011'
'12-Jan-2011'
'13-Jan-2011'
'14-Jan-2011'
```

This would be for one `uID`. So the `uID{366}` would be '06-019-5001'. For `uID{367}`, the dates would be the same, but the `Data{367}` values would be different.

I would want to find all of the cases where `Date` = '01-Jan-2011' since for each `uID`, there would be a `Date` = '01-Jan-2011' and a different `Data`, `Lat`, and `Lon`. Then, I would concatenate all of them into a column with the `Data` on that day (Same for Lat and Lon, but since they are the same size, it would be the same process)

Comment: A small example with a few values and cells would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your cell arrays of cell arrays of strings are of the same size (including uID), I would concatenate all the internal cells into a cell array of strings:

```
Data2 = cat(1,Data{:});
Date2 = cat(1,Date{:});
...
uID2 = cat(1,uID{:});
```

Then

```
idx = strcmp(uID2,'06-019-5001') & strcmp(Date2,'01-Jan-2011');
out = Data2(idx);
```

You can also create a table (in the late MATLAB versions) for much easier queries.

Comment: The thing is that I need to plot all the data from one day on a map eventually. This puts everything into a column vector, but it's one site after another. I'm looking for something like `Data2{i}` in which each i is a day with all the Data where Date is 01-Jan-2011 or any other day (I will turn Date into datenum eventually).

Comment: So you can do `i = strcmp(Date2,'01-Jan-2011');`

Comment: If you really want to group the data into cells try GROUP2CELL submission on FileExchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11192-group2cell Use Date2 as the group.

Comment: But how would I do it for all the uIDs and all the days?

Comment: I think would work if the strcmp is changed to find just all the data where the date is the same. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand your last comments. Have you tried my code in the answer? Do you understand how Date2, uID2, etc will look like? All your variables have exactly the same size, right?

Comment: Yes. I tried your code and all of my variables are the same size. But I am getting an empty cell. What I meant by my above comments is that I don't want just the data for Jan 01, 2011. I want to get the data for all the days between 2008 and 2014.

Comment: Which cell is empty? `out`? It means you don't have this particular combination of uID and Date.

Comment: In Data2, Date2 etc you get data for all the dates with easy filtering. You can sort these arrays by Date2, or use GROUP2CELL function to group them by date. What exactly format do you want?

Comment: I re-asked the question using what you provided. Can you take a look? Hopefully that one makes more sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396797/matlab-find-the-indexes-that-have-a-particular-date

Comment: So do you want to close this question? have you tried group2cell function? This is basically what your new question is about.