# MATLAB Find the indexes that have a particular date

Tags: matlab, find, reshape

I am trying to find the index in `Date3`, a column vector of date numbers from 01/01/2008 to 01/31/2014 that has been repeated many times, matches `day`. I basically want to organize idx into a cell array like `idx{i}` in which each cell is one day (So return all the indexes where Date3 equals day, where day is one of the days between 01/01/2008 and 01/31/2014. Eventually, I want to pull out the data for each day by applying the index I found to the variable `Data2` (Reshape Data2 so that instead of a long column vector of data concentrations, I'll have a cell array in which each cell is all the data from one day)

This is what I have been doing:

```
for day = datenum(2008,01,01):1:datenum(2014,01,31); % All the days under consideration
    idx = find(Date3, day); % Index of where Date3 equals the day under consideration
    Data_PM25 = Data2(idx); % Pull out the data based on the idx
end
```

Example: 
If `Date3` looks like the following (It's actually much larger and repeats many many more times)

```
  733408
  733409
  733410
  733411
  733412
  733413
  733414
  733415
  733416
  733417
  733418
  733419
  733420
  733421
  733408
  733409
  733410
  733411
  733412
  733413
  733414
  733415
  733416
  733417
  733418
  733419
  733420
  733421
```

I want idx to be

```
`idx{1}` = (1, 15) % Where 733408 repeats
`idx{2}` = (2, 16) % Where 733409 repeats
...
```

And then `Data2`, which looked like:

```
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
    '25.8'
    '26.1'
    '28.9'
    '37.5'
    '25.2'
    '20' 
    '32.3'
    '41' 
    '46.7'
    '28.2'
    '34.5'
    '31.8'
    '37.6'
    '45.5'
    '54.9'
    '54.8'
    '36.3'
    '18.5'
```

Will now look like

```
'Data_PM25{1}' = ([NaN], '25.2')
'Data_PM25{2}' = ([NaN], '20')
```

...

Of course, the actual outputs will be much longer than just two matches.

What appears to be happening though is that I am comparing every `day` against `Date3`, a list of days, so I am getting all the days back.

This question expands off of a previous question: [Find where a value matches and concatentate into column vector MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394583/find-where-a-value-matches-and-concatentate-into-column-vector-matlab)

Comment: You should make a reference to your first question.

Comment: How? Just link to it?

Comment: Yes, just say in the beginning something like "In addition to my [previous question]" and make a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find(ismember…) to find where a certain day shows up in the long column of Date3 and then used that to pull out all the data, Lat, and Lon from that day.

`group2cell` for some reason, created double the number of days there were supposed to be. Basically, it somehow pulled out two years in which the first year it pulled out (1:365 or 1:366) was random.

```
day = datenum(years(y), 01, 01):datenum(years(y), 12, 31); % Create a column vector of all days in one year
for d = 1:length(day)
    % Find index where Date3 matches one day, one day at a time
    ind{d} = find(ismember(datenum(Date3), day(d)) == 1);
    data_O3{d} = Data2(ind{d});
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: The result should be a cell array of vectors, each vector corresponding to the data from a given day.

This of course assumes Date3 and Data2 are the same size

```
 Date3=[733408
  733409
  733410
  733411
  733412
  733413
  733414
  733415
  733416
  733417
  733418
  733419
  733420
  733421
  733408
  733409
  733410
  733411
  733412
  733413
  733414
  733415
  733416
  733417
  733418
  733419
  733420
  733421];
Data2 = Date3.*50; % //just some dummy data for testing
Data_pm25=cell(0);
for day=datenum(2008,01,01):datenum(2014,01,01)
    idx=day==Date3;
    Data_pm25 = [Data_pm25,Data2(idx)];
end
```

The only problem I can see with this is if you don't have data for every day, you wouldn't necessarily know which day each cell is representing. This could easily be solved by storing a vector of dates with data.

Comment: FIND function will actually slow down the code. Just `idx=Date3==day;` should be enough. But I think it was just a typo. The OP want to organize the data into a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your other question try [GROUP2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11192-group2cell) function from FileExchange.

You can use it on index as

```
[newidx, uniqueDate] = group2cell(idx,Date2);
```

or directly on data

```
[Data_PM25, uniqueDate] = group2cell(Data2,Date2);
```

`uniqueDate` will be an array of all unique Dates. `uniqueDate(i)` will correspond to `Data_PM25(i)`.